# uibutton within custom uitablecell

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, uibutton

Im building an iphone app through xcode and objective c. building for ios5.0 min target.
I created a custom uitablecell and im loading this within a table in a view controller no problems. this cell contains a button. when the user taps this button within any of the cells i want it to call the same function within the view controller. The way i have done this in the past is by making the file owner of the custom cell the viewcontroller in question and then simply control drag the button into the view controller and place the ibaction function there. always works no problem. until now.

> -[__NSCFString loadMerchant:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8689e50 2012-05-24 09:56:14.630 [3217:16103] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString loadMerchant:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x8689e50'

this is the error im getting. I am making sure that the function is not accidently linked to the wrong button, that the function isnt also in the cell.m by mistake and any other simple mistakes i can think of.

Does anyone know the correct way to accomplish what im trying to do?

edit: custom cell

```
@interface TimelineCell : UITableViewCell


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *nameButton;


@end


@implementation TimelineCell


@synthesize nameButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self; }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state }

@end
```

below is the viewcontroller

```
 - (IBAction)loadMerchant:(id)sender;

 - (IBAction)loadMerchant:(id)sender { }
```

and thats it. crash happens when ever the button is tapped with above error

edit: dropping the link within the nib file and just maually add the action to the button seems to solve the issue but id still liek to know the cause of it if anyone can shed some light on that would be appreciated

made within cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 UIButton *b = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
 [b addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMerchant:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: sorry edited for some code there. but its very basic dont understand why its failing. when the same ahs worked so many times before

Comment: from where you are calling loadMerchant method, can you add that code as well?

Comment: Did you check **loadMerchant** method link from **mameButton** in .xib again?

Comment: rishi the loadmerchant is called from the link made from namebutton within the nib file and the ibaction within the viewcontroller. the physical call within my code does not exist. and i have double checked the link is made. if the link wasnt made it wouldnt even crash at all as it wouldnt know of the loadmerchant function anyway. its a mystery to me :(

Comment: I think this error means that the object on which you're calling loadMerchant has been released. If this method is not called in code then i'd recommend you make sure that instance of TimelineCell is not being release before it needs to be.

Comment: yeah its not getting released early and manually adding the action to the button works. but still unsure why the link through IB was failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i ended up doing was tagging the button within the nib file and then in code adding the target through code in the cell set up in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
UIButton *b = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
 [b addTarget:self action:@selector(loadMerchant:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

while this solves the problem I am still unsure as to why the link made through IB failed in the first place.

Comment: I believe you can use Interface Builder to solve this problem IF you don't connect to the "Files Owner", but instead connect to the custom object.